Connection to The Things Network whit LR-FHSS
Context
I'm currently trying to connect to TTN whit LR-FHSS modulation, this is suppose to be supported by the Things Stack (Check that here), I'm using a LR1110 (this DevKit), using the LoRaWAN 1.0.4, and the RP002 1.0.3 for the regional parameters, I'm in the EU863-870 region.
The LR1110 is working whit the followings parameters (extracted from TTN):
"settings": {
          "data_rate": {
            "lrfhss": {
              "operating_channel_width": 137000,
              "coding_rate": "1/3"
            }
          },
          "frequency": "868000000",
          "timestamp": 3695016880
     },

The problem
I'm trying to do an OTAA activation, I can see the data being received by the gateway in the TTN console, but in the application I'm getting the following error (the --- is data that I have deleted):
{
      "name": "ns.up.join.drop",
      "time": ----------------,
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "device_ids": {
            "device_id": "----------------",
            "application_ids": {
              "application_id": "----------------"
            },
            "dev_eui": ----------------,
            "join_eui": ----------------
          }
        }
      ],
      "data": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/ttn.lorawan.v3.ErrorDetails",
        "namespace": "pkg/networkserver",
        "name": "uplink_channel_not_found",
        "message_format": "uplink channel not found",
        "correlation_id": ----------------,
        "code": 5
      },
      "correlation_ids": [
        ----------------
      ],
      "origin": "ip-10-100-7-129.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
      "context": {
        "tenant-id": ----------------
      },
      "visibility": {
        "rights": [
          "RIGHT_APPLICATION_TRAFFIC_READ"
        ]
      },
      "unique_id": ----------------
    }

I looked it up, and is supposed to be an mismatch between the gateway / region / device settings.
The gateway is configured (on LR-FHSS) as follows:
The region in TTN is:
Europe 863-870 MHz (SF9 for RX2 - recommended)
LoRaWAN Specification 1.0.4
RP002 Regional Parameters 1.0.3
The device settings where mentioned at the begging, but here is more detailed information:
OCW= 136719_HZ
CR= 1/3
Frequency hopping grid = 3906_HZ
Header counts = 3
Modulation type = GMSK488(LR-FHSS)

The question
I'm not finding any mismatching information, and no violation to the RP002 1.0.3
What's the problem?
What should I do to solve this problem?
